# Build i386 image in GitHub workflow

Tags: docker, x86, github-actions

I've been looking over [this guide](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-jobs/choosing-the-runner-for-a-job) on how to choose the runner for a GitHub workflow (e.g., `ubuntu-22.04`).

Is there a way to specify the processor architecture of the runner?  My GitHub workflow builds and pushes a Docker image to Docker Hub and I'd like to create both i386 and x86_64 images.

Comment: Most x86-64 systems can run 32-bit binaries, so you don't actually need a 32-bit install of Ubuntu to test a `gcc -m32` build.  IDK if that helps; I haven't used github-actions, I'm here for the [x86] tag.  But naively I wonder if you could just have two separate actions, one that builds with `-m32`, the other than builds with the default `-m64` on 64-bit server VMs.

Comment: @PeterCordes, I hadn’t thought of that.  Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a GitHub Action or GitHub Actions workflow? It sounds like it's about a workflow and not an action. And, for building multi-arch docker images, see https://docs.docker.com/build/ci/github-actions/multi-platform/ and https://github.com/docker/build-push-action (i.e. `platforms` input parameter).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For building multi-arch docker images, you can follow [Multi-platform image with GitHub Actions](https://docs.docker.com/build/ci/github-actions/multi-platform/). It uses [docker/build-push-action](https://github.com/docker/build-push-action). You can use its [`platforms`](https://github.com/docker/build-push-action#inputs) input parameter to specify different platforms and architectures.